# jQuery popup will not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to make a jQuery popup, that pops up when the users clicks an image. I can make it work just like I want when I put it in a new html page, but once I put it on the page where I want it, the popup doesn't want to appear. Everything should be the same, so I don't understand why it doesn't work. Any help will be much appreciated.

Works:

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $(".myImages").click(function () 
        {
            $("#dialog-message").dialog
            ({
                modal: true,
                show: "fade", 
                height: 300, 
                width: 400, 
                buttons: {Ok: function() 
                         {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                         }
                } 
            });
        });
    });


</script>

<style>

    #dialog-message {
        display: none;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    .ui-dialog-titlebar-close{
        display: none;
    }

    .ui-dialog {
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="dialog-message" title="Håndtering">
        <p>Vi finder frem til netop den indlæringmetode, der virker på din hest, når du skal lære hesten nye ting. Hvis der er opstået problemer med fx benløft, opsadling eller lignende, vil vi sammen prøve at analysere, om der kan være en dybereliggende årsag, mentalt eller fysisk, der skal arbejdes med, før vi indlærer hesten nyt. I modsat fald kan vi risikere, at vi blot lærer hesten at ”overhøre” ubehaget.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="../HesteGitte/testing/billeder/Undervisning/haandtering.jpg" id="undervisningIMG" class="myImages" /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Undervisning</title>

<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="../baggrund/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $(".myImages").click(function () 
        {
            $("#dialog-message").dialog
            ({
                modal: true,
                show: "fade", 
                height: 300, 
                width: 400, 
                buttons: {Ok: function() 
                         {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                         }
                } 
            });
        });
    });


</script>

<style>

    #dialog-message {
        display: none;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    .ui-dialog-titlebar-close{
        display: none;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="dialog-message" title="Håndtering">
        <p>Vi finder frem til netop den indlæringmetode, der virker på din hest, når du skal lære hesten nye ting. Hvis der er opstået problemer med fx benløft, opsadling eller lignende, vil vi sammen prøve at analysere, om der kan være en dybereliggende årsag, mentalt eller fysisk, der skal arbejdes med, før vi indlærer hesten nyt. I modsat fald kan vi risikere, at vi blot lærer hesten at ”overhøre” ubehaget.</p>
    </div>
<div class="siteWrapper">
    <div class="contentWrapper">
        <div class="contentBackground">

            <p id="undervisningParagraph">
            <strong>Har du brug for hjælp til:</strong><br />
            </p>

            <div id="undervisningBoxWrapper">
                <div id="undervisningImageWrapper">
                    Håndtering<br />
                    <img src="../billeder/Undervisning/haandtering.jpg" id="undervisningIMG" class="myImages" /><br />
                </div>
                <div id="undervisningImageWrapper">
                    Trailertræning<br />
                    <img src="../billeder/Undervisning/trailertraening.jpg" id="undervisningIMG"/><br />
                </div>
                <div id="undervisningImageWrapper">
                    Longering<br />
                    <img src="../billeder/Undervisning/longering.jpg" id="undervisningIMG" /><br />
                </div>
                <div id="undervisningImageWrapper">
                    En god start med unghesten<br />
                    <img src="../billeder/Undervisning/unghest.jpg" id="undervisningIMG" /><br /> 
                </div>
                <div id="undervisningImageWrapper">
                    Grundopbygning af hesten<br />
                    <img src="../billeder/Undervisning/genopbyg.jpg" id="undervisningIMG" /><br />
                </div>
                <div id="undervisningImageWrapper">
                    Omtræning af hesten<br />
                    <img src="../billeder/Undervisning/omtraening.jpg" id="undervisningIMG" /><br />
                </div>
                <div id="undervisningImageWrapper">
                    Styrkelse af samspillet<br />
                    <img src="../billeder/Undervisning/samspil.jpg" id="undervisningIMG" /><br />
                </div>
                <div id="undervisningImageWrapper">
                    Tackling af negative oplevelser<br />
                    <img src="../billeder/Undervisning/rideangst.jpg" id="undervisningIMG" /><br />
                </div>
                <div id="undervisningImageWrapper">
                    Undervisning af børn<br />
                    <img src="../billeder/Undervisning/boern.jpg" id="undervisningIMG" /><br />
                </div>
            </div>

            <p id="undervisningParagraph">
            <br />
            Så er min undervisning måske noget for dig.<br />
            <br />  
            Undervisningen kan foregå, hvor det er relevant, dvs hos dig, i terrænet og, fra kommende sommer, på min ridebane.<br />
            <br /> 
            Ved regelmæssig undervisning aftaler vi "lektier" fra gang til gang.<br />
            <br /> 
            <strong>Pris:</strong> Lektion á 45 min 150 kr + evt. kørsel 1,5 kr pr km, som deles, hvis I er flere samme sted.<br />
             <br />
            Der er en rabat på 25 kr for medlemmer af <a href="http://www.hestelaug.dk//" id="pageLink">Hannenovskovens Hestelaug</a><br /> 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I think the code to include jquery needs to be above the code that includes jquery-ui

Comment: You are completely right. Thanks a whole lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second one only the first image has the targeted class, and the issue is the swapping of the scripts, you have to load jQuery ***before*** you can load jQuery UI